# How to bind View with relevant model when two models(Tuple) are there

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working in MVC 4 and want to bind two models in view for which i used Tuple, and now i want to get values from both models in two different Divs but i am getting the following error:

```
here is my Controller code:

        public ActionResult Edit()
        {
            CygnusInternalResponseViewModel result = new CygnusInternalResponseViewModel();
            result = new Logic(CApplicationId, CurrentCompanyId).GetProducts();
            if (result.Success)
                return View(result.Model);

            ProductOrderViewModel objparent = new ProductOrderViewModel();
            List<ProductOrderViewModel> viewmodel = new List<ProductOrderViewModel>();
            viewmodel.Add(objparent);
            return View(viewmodel.AsEnumerable());

          //  return View();

        }
```

here is my model code:

```
    public class ProductOrderViewModel
    {
        public List<ProductViewModel> Products { get; set; }

        public List<OrderViewModel> Orders { get; set; }
    }
```

Please guide me to tackle this issue..Following is my Code

```
@model Cygnus.Global.ViewModels.ProductOrderViewModel
@using Cygnus.Global.ViewHelpers;
@using Cygnus.Global.ViewModels;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <div id="productarea">
        <div id="tabs-1">
             @foreach (var pd in Model.Products)
            {


                <div>
                    <div style=" border: 1px solid black; margin-top:5px; padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;" class="media p-t20px m-tn
                                      ">
                        <div class="left m-r10px">

                            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o comments-icon cmtIcon"></i>
                        </div>

                        <div class="media-body">
                            <p>
                                <span class="cmtText"> | @pd.Name | @pd.UnitPrice </span>

                            </p>




                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



            }
        </div>

    </div>
```

Your Order

```
    <img src="~/Content/themes/base/images/locationicon.png"   />
    @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Orders.Count; i++) { @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Orders[i].Area, new { @name = "area", @style = "width:295px; height:25px;margin-left:5px;" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Orders[i].Area)}
    <br /><br /><br />
    <img style="margin-left:20px;" src="~/Content/themes/base/images/timeicon.png" title="Delivery Time" />   1 hr <img style="margin-left:60px;" src="~/Content/themes/base/images/deliveryicon.png" title="Delivery Free" />   Free<img style="margin-left:60px;" src="~/Content/themes/base/images/walleticon.png" title="Minimum Order" />   Rs.1000
    <br /><br />
    <div style="height:150px;background-color:#fff;margin-left:-11px;margin-right:1px;">
        <br /><br /><br />

     <label style="float:right;color:red;margin-right:10px;">Start by Adding Items to Order!</label>   



    </div>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Orders.Count; i++) { 
    @Html.LabelFor(m =>m.Orders[i].SubTotal)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Orders[i].SubTotal, new  {@readonly = "readonly" ,@style = "width:100px; float:right;margin-top:-21px;" })
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Orders[i].Discount)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Orders[i].Discount, new { @readonly = "readonly", @style = "width:100px; float:right;margin-top:-21px;" })
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Orders[i].DeliveryFee)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Orders[i].DeliveryFee, new { @readonly = "readonly", @style = "width:100px; float:right;margin-top:-21px;" })
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Orders[i].TotalAmount)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Orders[i].TotalAmount, new { @readonly = "readonly", @style = "width:100px; float:right;margin-top:-21px;" })
    }<br /><br />
    <input id="btnproceed" type="button" value="Proceed to Order" />
</div>
<div id="customerdetails">
    <label>Your Information</label><br />

   @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Orders.Count; i++) { 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Orders[i].Customer, new { @placeholder = "Enter Your Full Name" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Orders[i].Customer)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Orders[i].Phone, new { @placeholder = "Enter Your Cell Number" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Orders[i].Phone)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Orders[i].Address, new {@rows = 3, @cols = 2, @style = "width:300px;" , @placeholder = "Enter Your  Complete Delivery Address" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Orders[i].Address)

   }
  <input id="btnback" type="button" value="Back" />  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Save" />

</div>
```

```
}
```

Comment: You cannot use a `tuple` for binding to form controls. Use a view model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i need two viewmodels then what should i do ?

Comment: you don't need 2 view models - you need one view model with 2 properties.

Comment: i have did so but getting error on foreach line does not contain a definition for 'Product' and no extension method 'Product'

Comment: @StephenMuecke now i am getting error on second div that is does not contain a definition for 'Area' and no extension method 'Area' accepting a first argument of type

Comment: @StephenMuecke hello, are you there

Comment: Yes, but your responding to hutchonoid's answer. ANd you have edited your question to show a view model (but the question was about a `tuple`) but the view code still shows `@model Tuple<ProductViewModel,OrderViewModel>` so I can understand whats your real code and what not. Based on your new model where both properties are collections, you need to use a `for` loop to generate your controls

Comment: @StephenMuecke It's a moving target this one, feel free to intervene. :)

Comment: @hutchonoid, Based on the question being changed and no longer making sense (and not reproducible) I'm voting to close, but since the model now appears to be 2 collection properties, suggest you add the usage inside a `for` loop for the form controls

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have edited my question please have a look now

Comment: @AhmadCheema It's tricky without seeing the errors too. Please add the other errors as updates to question and I can try and help.

Comment: @hutchonoid Error:  does not contain a definition for 'Area' and no extension method 'Area' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Comment: @AhmadCheema, You have changed your model property to `List<OrderViewModel>` - `List<T>` does not contain a property named `Area` - you now need a `@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Orders.Count; i++) { @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Orders[i].Area) ... }`.

Comment: And in future, do not completely change your question making all the comments and answers useless (append the new code instead) . And limit your code to only the minimum necessary - you only needed to show the view for one or 2 properties - don't make us wade though all this

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have changed that all but at the end getting this error:The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Cygnus.Global.ViewModels.ProductViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Cygnus.Global.ViewModels.ProductOrderViewModel'.

Comment: Another error that is self explanatory - your GET method does not pass an instance of `ProductOrderViewModel` to the view - your passing a `List<ProductViewModel>` to the view, hence the error. Fix your controller code.

Comment: Dear @StephenMuecke i have uploaded my controller code ..please guide me through

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87266/discussion-between-ahmadcheema-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 2):

Create a class that contains the two models and populated them from your controller:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
 public List<ProductViewModel> Products {get;set;}
 public OrderViewModel Order {get; set;}
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@model FooViewModel
// code ommited
@foreach (var pd in Model.Products)
{
// rest of code
```

Also note that if the rest of the fields are related to the order it would be within the `Order` property i.e:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m =>m.Order.SubTotal)
```

Comment: getting error on @foreach line does not contain a definition for 'Product' and no extension method 'Product'

Comment: @AhmadCheema It should be `Model.Products` not `Model.Product` mind.

Comment: dear i have written Product in model so cannot be written with extra s here...right ?

Comment: Dear now i am getting error at line Line 72:         <img src="~/Content/themes/base/images/locationicon.png"   />@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Area, new ERROR:Cygnus.Global.ViewModels.ProductOrderViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'Area' and

Comment: @AhmadCheema Just change it to `public List<ProductViewModel> product { get; set; }` to `public List<ProductViewModel> Products { get; set; }`

Comment: @AhmadCheema I'm guessing `Area` is in your order object so it would be `m.Order.Area,`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87267/discussion-between-ahmadcheema-and-hutchonoid).